# Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) in Clion

Tags: c, clion

I'm at early stage of learning C. My program should find the maximum number of the first column of two-dimensional array. But my program not only doesn't find the maximum, it doesn't work at all. So when I run the program, i get output: `Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)`.
My program you can see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int numberOfStrings, numberOfColumns;

    scanf("%d %d", &numberOfStrings, &numberOfColumns);
    int number[1000][1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &number[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int maxOfNumbers = number[0][0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfStrings; ++i) {
        if (number[i][0] > maxOfNumbers) {
            maxOfNumbers = number[i][0];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", maxOfNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what inputs does it fail on?

Comment: Stack overflow? `int number[1000][1000];` is using a lot of stack memory. For now, just move it out of `main()` so it is global, and see if that runs ok.

Comment: @nz_21 it doesn't even want me to input

Comment: Run it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mo7Wqc) show us a reproducible example

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you are right, it works now, thank you

Comment: Ideally you should use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate the memory.

Comment: How do you plan to provide million text inputs?
Even from file redirection it is not fast.

Comment: it's just condition of the problem, i didn't plan to input so large array, nevermind